# Typescript publish to NPM without JS

Tags: typescript, npm

How to publish my `*.ts` file to NPM that only contain type & interface definition?

There is no exported javascript function, object, etc.
Should I delete this? `"main": "index.js",` -or- replace with `"main": "dist/types.ts",`

Should I compile `*.ts` to `*.d.ts`?

The types.js:

```
export type Optional<T>                    = T|null|undefined
export type OptionalOrFalse<T>             = Optional<T|false>
export type SingleOrArray<T>               = T|T[]

export type DeepArray<T>                   = (T|DeepArray<T>)[] // ===       T[]  |  T[][]  |  T[][][]  |  ...
export type SingleOrDeepArray<T>           = T|DeepArray<T>     // === T  |  T[]  |  T[][]  |  T[][][]  |  ...

export type Factory<T>                     = () => T
export type ProductOrFactory<T>            = T|Factory<T>
export type ProductOrFactoryDeepArray<T>   = (ProductOrFactory<T> | ProductOrFactoryDeepArray<T>)[] // ===         T[]|F[]  |  T[][]|F[][]  |  T[][][]|F[][][]  |  ...
export type ProductOrFactoryOrDeepArray<T> =  ProductOrFactory<T> | ProductOrFactoryDeepArray<T>    // === T|F  |  T[]|F[]  |  T[][]|F[][]  |  T[][][]|F[][][]  |  ...

export type Dictionary<TValue>             = { [key: string]: TValue }
export type ValueOf<TDictionary>           = TDictionary[keyof TDictionary]
export type DictionaryOf<TDictionary>      = Dictionary<ValueOf<TDictionary>>
```

Comment: i think you might need to export like a namespace and the file should be called ".d.ts" as far as i know for type definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at examples from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) (e.g. `@types/...` packages).

Based on this, I believe:

- `"main"` can be an empty string (`""`)
- `"types"` should point to your `"index.d.ts"`
- Your package should not include any `*.ts` files (it should contain `*.d.ts` files instead)

This might also be useful to read through:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

Comment: right now, i still include an empty `index.js` generated by TS. Not really empty, just unuseful code `export {};`